# Can I use my personal Photoshop subscriber license for a commercial purpose? (Germany)

Tags: software, licensing, germany

I have the *Individuals Creative Cloud Photo Subscription (annual subscription)*. I'm paying this on my own and use it mainly at home. Now I want to use Photoshop for several things in the company I'm working in, is it allowed?

I'm from Germany, if this is relevant. I already asked the support but didn't get a clear answer, I got only a link to [Licenses and Terms of Use | Adobe](https://www.adobe.com/de/legal/licenses-terms.html).

I registered online on the Adobe page and bought the following ([Pricing Table](https://www.adobe.com/creativecloud/plans.html)) and pay monthly via PayPal.

[image: a screenshot of a payment page, USD20 for a Photoshop Photography, twenty gigabyte plan][3]

Comment: Hi, welcome to law.SE! The page you link to does not actually show a license called "Single User - Creative Cloud Photo Subscription". Also, it may not only matter that you are from Germany, but also where you bought the subscription (store, online, on which site), because that may influence the license terms that govern your subscription. Please edit to add this information.

Comment: Thank you @sleske I corrected and added information you mentioned.